# I'm stuck at the chasm in Scanner Sombre

Tags: scanner-sombre

I've played and replayed from the start point to the chasm multiple times, and I'm pretty certain there are no alternative routes, but I cannot find any way to get across the chasm.

I have tried jumping across from every closest point multiple times, and even tried sliding down the slopes at each end. Even if I fall and point the scanner up I don't see any clues.

I assume I must get across to the device on the other side, but how?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many, many falls trying to jump at every angle between the outcrops, I have found the way to get across.

> Don't try and jump.
>  Simply hug the wall to the left - there is a narrow ledge. Follow it round to the leftmost end and there is a small jump to the other side, where another ledge brings you back up to the Burst Scanner. In fact the location I stood to take the screenshot in the post above is exactly on the path to go round the ledge. D'oh!